# Generate constructor call with build macro

Tags: macros, haxe

How can I generate a `main()` (access) method for a Haxe class with a constructor call?

For example

```
static function main() new App()

function new() {
    //....
}
```

and I want to create this with macro, like this:

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class Build {
    macro public static function buildFields():Array<Field> {
        var fields:Array<Field> = Context.getBuildFields();
        var cls = Context.getLocalClass().get();
        var pack = cls.pack.concat([cls.name]);
        var name = pack.join(".");

        fields.push({
            name: "main",
            access: [Access.APublic, Access.AStatic],
            kind: FieldType.FFun({
                expr: macro {
                    Type.createInstance(Type.resolveClass($v{name}), []);
                },
                args: [],
                ret: null
            }),
            pos: Context.currentPos()
        });

        return fields;
    }
}
```

```
@:build(Build.buildFields())
class App {
    function new() {
        //....
    }
}
```

This generates the `main()` method fine, but I'm not sure how to generate `new App()` instead of resorting to `Type.createInstance()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate a constructor call like `new App()`, you can reify a [`haxe.macro.TypePath`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/TypePath.html) as documented [here](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-expression.html).

```
var typePath:haxe.macro.TypePath = {
    pack: cls.pack,
    name: cls.name
}
```

```
expr: macro new $typePath(),
```

Btw, instead of manually constructing fields like that, I would suggest using [class reification](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-class.html), which lets you use regular Haxe syntax for declaring fields:

```
fields = fields.concat((macro class {
    public static function main() {
        new $typePath();
    }
}).fields);
```