# How to return a class instance with an expression macro?

Tags: haxe

Driver code

```
//---------------- Main.hx ------------------------------------------------------------------
import core.reflection.ReflectionTools;
import core.SomeClass;
class Main{
   public static function main(){
      var s = new SomeClass();
      ReflectionTools.info(s);
   }
}
```

The macro

```
//---------------- ReflectionTools.hx -----------------------------------------------------
class RelectionTools {
    public static macro function info(obj:Expr):Expr{
        var pos = Context.currentPos();
        var block = [];
        var result:Dynamic;
        var type:Type=Context.typeof(obj);        
        result=(switch(type){
            case TInst(t, params):new RelectionClass(t, params);
            case TEnum(t, params):new ReflectionEnum(t, params);
            case TDynamic(t):new ReflectionDynamic(t);
            case TFun(args, ret):new ReflectionFunction(args, ret);
            case TMono(t):new ReflectionMonomorph(t);
            case TLazy(f):new ReflectionLazy(f);
            case TAbstract(t, params):new ReflectionAbstract(t, params);
            case TType(t, params):new ReflectionTypeDefinition(t, params);
            case TAnonymous(a):new ReflectionAnonymousStructure(a);
        });
        return $v{result};
    }
}
```

Haxe Compiler:

> Expected Expr but got core.reflection.RelectionClass (see dump/decoding_error.txt for details)

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304292/generate-constructor-call-with-build-macro

Answer (score 1):

Macro is a compile time feature, not runtime feature, you can't return class instance. Instead, you have to return expression which creates a new instance (I don't have your classes, so I use here my class)

```
var type=Context.typeof(obj); 
return (switch(type){
    case TInst(t, params):macro new MyClass();//RelectionClass(t, params);
    case TEnum(t, params):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionEnum(t, params);
    case TDynamic(t):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionDynamic(t);
    case TFun(args, ret):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionFunction(args, ret);
    case TMono(t):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionMonomorph(t);
    case TLazy(f):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionLazy(f);
    case TAbstract(t, params):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionAbstract(t, params);
    case TType(t, params):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionTypeDefinition(t, params);
    case TAnonymous(a):macro new MyClass();//ReflectionAnonymousStructure(a);
});
return macro null;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a build macro (which allows returning class instances) but it is an expression macro. The best way to mimic class functionality is with abstracts.

```
/* Solution Description
1. a custom Json abstract with underlying type {} and with implicit   
    casts to underlying type. See Json.hx
2. abstracts which reflect possible Type enums with underlying custom 
   Json abstract and forwards. See example ReflectionPrimitive.hx
   and mimic inheritance by underlying types as superclass 
   see example ReflectionFunction.hx 
3. uses same instantiation code as original class instantiation 
   but now they are abstracts (see PROBLEM(The macro). Solved! */
```

Step 1.
a custom Json abstract with underlying type {} and with implicit casts to 
underlying type.

```
// ---------------- Json.hx ----------------------------------------------
package core.ds.json;
import haxe.Serializer;
import haxe.Unserializer;
import haxe.Json as J;

abstract Json({}) from ({}) to ({}) {
    public inline function new(?data:{}){
        this=data;
        if(this==null){
            this={};
        }
    }
    @:arrayAccess 
    public inline function get(key:String):Dynamic{
        if(exists(key)){
            return Reflect.field(this,key);
        } 
        return null;
    }
    @:arrayAccess 
    public inline function set(key:String, value:Dynamic):Dynamic{
        Reflect.setField(this, key, value);
        return value;
    }   

    public inline function isEmpty(key:String):Bool{
        return !isSet(key) || (exists(key) && (  get(key)=="" || get(key)==''|| get(key)==null || get(key)==0  ));
    }

    public inline function isSet(key:String):Bool{
        return exists(key) && get(key)!=null;
    }

    public inline function exists(key:String):Bool {
        return Reflect.hasField(this, key);
    } 
    @:to
    public inline function toMap():Map<String, Dynamic>{
        var result:Map<String, Dynamic>=new Map<String, Dynamic>();
        var fields:Array<String>=Reflect.fields(this);
        for (f in fields){
            result.set(f, Reflect.field(this, f));
        }
        return result;
    }
    @:to
    public inline function toJsonString():String{
        return J.stringify(this,null," ");
    }

    public inline function values():Array<Dynamic>{
        var result:Array<Dynamic>=[];
        var keys:Array<String>=keys();
        for(k in keys){
            result.push(Reflect.field(this,k));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public inline function keys():Array<String>{
        return Reflect.fields(this);
    }

    public inline function clone():Json{
        return Unserializer.run(Serializer.run(this));
    }

    public var length(get,never):Int;


    private inline function get_length():Int{
        return keys().length;
    }

    public inline function keyValueIterator():KeyValueIterator<String, Dynamic>{
        return toMap().keyValueIterator();
    }


    @:from 
    public static function fromJsonString(json:String):Json{
        return J.parse(json);
    }
    @:from 
    public static function fromMap(map:Map<String, Dynamic>):Json{
        var result={};
        for (k=>v in map){
            Reflect.setField(result, k, v);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Step 2.
 abstracts which reflect possible Type enums with underlying custom Json abstract and forwards. See example ReflectionPrimitive.hx and mimic inheritance by underlying types as superclass see example ReflectionFunction.hx

```
//---------------- ReflectionPrimitive.hx ----------------------------------------------

@:forward()
abstract ReflectionPrimitive(core.ds.json.Json) from core.ds.json.Json to core.ds.json.Json{
    public inline function new(nameType:String){
        this=new core.ds.json.Json({data:new core.ds.json.Json(), info:new core.ds.json.Json({nameType:nameType})});
    }
    public var data(get, set):core.ds.json.Json;
    public var info(get, set):core.ds.json.Json;
    private function get_data():core.ds.json.Json {
        return this["data"];
    }
    private function set_data(value:core.ds.json.Json):core.ds.json.Json {
        this["data"]=value;
        return this;
    }
    private function get_info():core.ds.json.Json {
        return this["info"];
    }
    private function set_info(value:core.ds.json.Json):core.ds.json.Json {
        this["info"]=value;
        return this;
    }
 }
```

Mimmicking inheritance

```
//---------------- ReflectionFunction.hx ----------------------------------------------
@:forward(data, info, get, isEmpty, isSet, exists, toMap, toJsonString, values, keys, clone, length, keyValueIterator, fromJsonString, fromMap)
abstract ReflectionFunction(ReflectionPrimitive) from ReflectionPrimitive to ReflectionPrimitive{
    public inline function new(args:Array<{t:Type, opt:Bool, name:String}>, ret:Type){
        this=new ReflectionPrimitive(NameType.FUNCTION);
        var newArgs=new Array<core.ds.json.Json>();
        for(a in args){
           newArgs.push(new core.ds.json.Json(a));
        }
        this.data=this.data.set("args",newArgs).set("ret", ret);
    }
    public var args(get, never):Array<core.ds.json.Json>;
    public var ret(get,never):Type;

    private function get_args():Array<core.ds.json.Json>{
        return this.data.get("args");
    }
    private function get_ret():Type{
        return this.data.get("ret");
    }

}
```

Leave the macro untouched it will work now.